# how to enforce single sign on using oauth 2.0 with three apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I have an Angular app (A) that successfully gets an access token from an oauth2 provider implemented using rails 4 and doorkeeper gem (B). After the angular app gets the access token, it needs to redirect the user to another rails app (C) without requiring the user to authenticate with app B again.

How do I bypass the second authentication?

App C currently has an /auth/callback route that reads the oauth2 token out of request.env['omniauth.auth']

App A sends requests to App B passing oauth2 access token in the Authorization header.

App C also sends requests to App B passing oauth2 access token in the Authorization header.

I was thinking that App A would redirect to App C with the access token in the query string. App C would need to be modified to read the token from the query string. Is there a better way?

Comment: I use to have a very similar problem as yours, except that my users can access App C directly from the browser. I handled this case by following this tutorial http://subinsb.com/set-same-cookie-on-different-domains. Instead of registering cookie, I'm setting my token in the localStorage to make it works :)